# matplotlib for temperature heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want draw a temperature profile using matplotlib.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap

# Load temperature data from CSV file
file_path = 'tcdata.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)

# Extract coordinates and temperatures from the data
x = data['x']
y = data['y']
temperatures = data['temp']

# Set the radius for the circle
radius = 150

# Create a grid for interpolation
grid_x, grid_y = np.mgrid[-radius:radius:300j, -radius:radius:300j]

# Interpolate the temperature data over the grid
grid_temperatures = griddata((x, y), temperatures, (grid_x, grid_y), method='cubic')

# Create a circular mask to limit the heatmap within the circle
mask = np.sqrt(grid_x**2 + grid_y**2) > radius
grid_temperatures = np.ma.masked_where(mask, grid_temperatures)

# Create a custom color map: blue for the lowest, red for the highest, and green for intermediate temperatures
cmap = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('custom_heatmap', ['blue', 'green', 'red'], N=256)

# Plot the heatmap
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
plt.imshow(grid_temperatures.T, extent=(-radius, radius, -radius, radius), origin='lower', cmap=cmap)
plt.colorbar(label='Temperature (°C)')

# Set the title
plt.title('Circular Temperature Distribution Heatmap')

# Disable the grid
plt.grid(False)

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

csv file data is as follows：

```
| x | y | temp|
| -140 | 0 | 397.32 |
| -100 | 90 | 396.76 |
| -100 | -90 | 396.34 |
| -70 | 0 | 396 |
| -50 | 44 | 395.34 |
| -50 | -44 | 395.57 |
| 0 | 140 | 396.37 |
| 0 | 70 | 395.82 |
| 0 | 0 | 393.52 |
| 0 | -70 | 393.52 |
| 0 | -140 | 395.61|
| 50 | 44 | 395.82 |
| 50 | -44 | 394.08 |
| 50 | -44 | 394.08 |
| 70 | 0 | 394.62 |
| 100 | 90 | 395.79 |
| 100 | -90 | 395.25 |
| 140 | 0 | 396.12 |
```

The data is sparse, how to add more data by using proper interpolation algorithms?

and it shows octagon profile rather than circular distribution，how to adjust the codes to achieve it？

I searched online but didn't get the result I wanted.

Comment: Maybe your input data is too sparse? It's hard to tell without fully reproducible test data.

Comment: Please share the data as text, not an image.

Comment: As @JohanC mentioned already: You don't have enough data. The octagon you see is exactly the outer shape spanned with the grid (x,y) that you give the picture. If you want it to be more circular, you can provide more points to interpolate in between.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that nothing can be interpolated outside the octagon you see. Even if you don't set the mask, you will see the same octagon! Here is a solution: Can you provide data for the corners of the image? I added

`-150, -150, 398`
`150, 150, 398`
`150, -150, 398`
`-150, 150, 398`

to the csv to test. You can see that then the interpolation works and your circled mask can be seen. If you have better numbers, feel free to include them. But since it will only have a minor effect in the regions you were missing, it might be fine like that already.